# Error logs converted into Excel charts

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program for work, just to make my life easier but I digress I am over my head on this one.

The Program needs to select and open a directory where there is multiple folders and in those folders are multiple txt files containing errors. The program needs to select all those txt files in the folders and store them into arrays. The program should give the user a search box to select the name of the error you require then iterate through them. The the catch is that the program should then export the data to MS Excel where the figures are made into a stat per month.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your title, it is not a good one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: It has been a back and forth, deleting of codes that does not work. I'll upload some code. But at this stage I am struggling with the multiple text files from a bunch of folders being saved into a array where search phrases inputted by the user can be used to iterate through the txt files and select certain strings.

Comment: What I see here - you have a strong vision what should be done and how it can look like. So, what's the problem? Write library for data processing, create some front-end for it (WPF, WF, ASP.NET). Profit.